# T-SQL - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to figure out why my `case` statement is not working.  Probably something simple.  Error below the code.  I don't work w/ SQL too terribly much.

```
case month(getdate())
    when '1' then
        select 
            'mmarks@fd.com' as EmailAddress, 
            'mmarks@fd.com' as SubscriberKey, 
            sum(case when isclaimed = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'RemainingActiveCouponCodes' 
        from january_sms_welcome_codes
    when '2' then
        select 
            'mmarks@fd.com' as EmailAddress, 
            'mmarks@fd.com' as SubscriberKey, 
            sum(case when isclaimed = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'RemainingActiveCouponCodes' 
        from february_sms_welcome_codes
end
```

[image]

Comment: Where's the *rest* of the query? If you get a complaint about `case` it means it's used in a place it shouldn't. BTW `CASE` is used *in* SQL  statements, it *can't* contain statements. Are you trying to use it like a `switch` in C?

Comment: Then Part you are returning so many items,it can return one column but not multiple

Comment: Also consider that trying to select from a different table based on some criteria is *not* going to execute faster than querying all tables and using `UNION ALL`. It will only result in generating a non-efficient execution plan. In fact, if each table had a `month` column with the proper constraints. SQL Server could pick the proper table to search by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CASE is an expression that returns a value, not a statement on its own. Rephrase like this:

```
declare @@month int
set @@month=month(getdate())
if @@month=1 begin
    select 
        'mmarks@fd.com' as EmailAddress, 
        'mmarks@fd.com' as SubscriberKey, 
        sum(case when isclaimed = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'RemainingActiveCouponCodes'
    from january_sms_welcome_codes
end
if @@month=2 begin
    select 
        'mmarks@fd.com' as EmailAddress, 
        'mmarks@fd.com' as SubscriberKey, 
        sum(case when isclaimed = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'RemainingActiveCouponCodes' 
    from february_sms_welcome_codes
end
```